# Adding a previous row value with current row

Tags: sql, h2

I want to add a new column that calculate the daily gross amount call GrossAmount with some calculation.
DailyTransaction(day1) + cash_in(day2) - DailyExpense(day2) = GrossAmount(day2)
But i have no idea on how to do it, i have tried several way but its doesn't work.

```
ALTER TABLE TESTING ADD COLUMN GrossAmount DECIMAL AS 
  (SELECT t1.DailyTransaction + t2.DailyTransaction 
   FROM TESTING t1 
   INNER JOIN TESTING t2 
   WHERE t1.LOANID = t2.LOANID - 1)
```

[image]

Comment: Have you had a look at the `LAG` function on H2? https://www.h2database.com/html/functions-window.html#lag

Comment: Hi Sean, thanks for replying, i  never try this before, but i have tried the LAST_VALUE(), its seem like doesn't work up,  I am not sure did I implement it correctly because i am actually new for this h2 sql management....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the below perhaps. Not sure what you are trying to do with the `ALTER TABLE`. Is this meant to be a calculated column?

```
select DailyTransaction + lag(DailyTransaction, 1, 0) 
        over (order by LOANID), DailyTransaction, LOANID
  from TESTING
 order by LOANID
```